# Image upload from photo library in ios using AFNetworking?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

I am developing an app in which a user need to register. There is an image upload option where the user can pick an image from the photo library in iPhone. I have used AFNetworking for uploading. But there is error in multipart uploading, Error log attached with this question. If anyone know the solution please help me

Thanks in advance.

**iOS PART**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage * image = info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%c%c.jpg", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970], arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a', arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a'];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
   // NSLog(@"DATA %@",data);
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSString *key1 = @"123";
    NSString *key2 = @"asdf";


     [manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.100/fileupload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data
                                    name:@"uploadedfile"
                                fileName:fileName mimeType:@"image/png"];

        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[key1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"email"];

        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[key2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"website"];

        // etc.
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error serializing %@", error);
        }
        NSLog(@"Dictionary %@", JSON);    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

**php PART**

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    echo "file=".$file; //is empty, but shouldn't

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo $file;
    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
    ?>
```

**ERROR**

```
  imageupload[23252:237255] Error serializing Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Something looked like a 'false' but wasn't around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fee21fe1590 {NSDebugDescription=Something looked like a 'false' but wasn't around character 0.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quick looked your code and found

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

And you specified mimeType as "image/png", I think this may cause error.

Comment: so what should be the mimeType?

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's responseSerializer is AFJSONResponseSerializer by default  and your php script don't seem return json response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void) uploadImage {

NSString *imagePath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userimage"];
NSString * urlString = [stagingURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"user/" withString:@""];
NSString * uploadURL = @"Your URL where image to be uploaded";
NSLog(@"uploadImageURL: %@", uploadURL);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]], 0.5);

NSString *queryStringss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",uploadURL];
queryStringss = [queryStringss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];

[manager POST:queryStringss parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"file" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 }
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
     [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
     NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
 }];}
```

Comment: how to get the image path from image picker controller?